# Set confidence levels in seaborn kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm completely new to seaborn, so apologies if this is a simple question, but I cannot find anywhere in the documentation a description of how the levels plotted by n_levels are controlled in kdeplot. This is an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y=np.random.randn(2,10000)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sns.kdeplot(x,y, shade=True,shade_lowest=False, ax=ax,n_levels=3,cmap="Reds")
plt.show()
```

This is the resulting plot: [image]

I would like to be able to know what confidence levels are shown, so that I can label my plot "shaded regions show the (a,b,c) percentage confidence intervals." I would naively assume that n_levels is somehow related to equivalent "sigmas" in a Gaussian, but from the example that doesn't look to be the case.

Ideally, I would like to be able to specify the intervals shown by passing a tuple to kdeplot, such as:

```
levels=[68,95,99]
```

and plot these confidence regions.

EDIT: Thanks to @Goyo and @tom I think I can clarify my question, and come partway to the answer I am looking for. As pointed out, `n_levels` is passed to `plt.cotourf` as `levels`, and so a list *can* be passed. But `sns.kdeplot` plots the PDF, and the values in the PDF don't correspond to the confidence intervals I am looking for (since these correspond to integration of the PDF).

What I need to do is pass `sns.kdeplot` the `x,y` values of the integrated (and normalized) PDF, and then I will be able to enter e.g. `n_levels=[0.68,0.95,0.99,1]`.

EDIT 2: I have now solved this problem. See below. I use a 2d normed histogram to define the confidence intervals, which I then pass as levels to the normed kde plot. Apologies for repetition, I could make a function to return levels, but I typed it all out explicitly.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Generate some random data
x,y=np.random.randn(2,100000)

# Make a 2d normed histogram
H,xedges,yedges=np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=40,normed=True)

norm=H.sum() # Find the norm of the sum
# Set contour levels
contour1=0.99
contour2=0.95
contour3=0.68

# Set target levels as percentage of norm
target1 = norm*contour1
target2 = norm*contour2
target3 = norm*contour3

# Take histogram bin membership as proportional to Likelihood
# This is true when data comes from a Markovian process
def objective(limit, target):
    w = np.where(H>limit)
    count = H[w]
    return count.sum() - target

# Find levels by summing histogram to objective
level1= scipy.optimize.bisect(objective, H.min(), H.max(), args=(target1,))
level2= scipy.optimize.bisect(objective, H.min(), H.max(), args=(target2,))
level3= scipy.optimize.bisect(objective, H.min(), H.max(), args=(target3,))

# For nice contour shading with seaborn, define top level
level4=H.max()
levels=[level1,level2,level3,level4]

# Pass levels to normed kde plot
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sns.kdeplot(x,y, shade=True,ax=ax,n_levels=levels,cmap="Reds_d",normed=True)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is now the following: [image: kde with confidence levels]

The levels are slightly wider than I expect, but I think this is correct.

Comment: I *think* that `n_levels` simply divides the range between min/max values into `n` equally sized steps.

Comment: it seems like you should be able to remove `n_levels` and pass in `levels=[X,Y,Z]` (since levels will just get passed on to `plt.contourf`). But I'm not sure what the X,Y,Z levels should be, since the values of the contour plot are not going to equal your percentage confidence levels.

Comment: @David I think you should clarify your question. It is about "setting confidence level in seaborn kdeplot" and now I realiza that my answer do not addres it, but I cannot figure out what that could possibly mean. For which parameter do you want to compute confidence intervals? And how is it related to kde, which is a non-parametric estimation?

Comment: I just found this as I want to do something similar. What this code is really doing is setting the contours to percentiles of the empirical density function generated by the histogram. I'm no stats wizard but I don't think it's quite the same as a confidence interval in the usual sense of that phrase. It's also worth pointing out that this code only works when the 2d histogram bins are all the same area (which is what `np.histogram2d` does by default).

Answer (score 1):

The levels are not confidente intervals or sigmas but values of the estimated pdf. You **are able** to pass the levels as a list instead as n_levels.

**EDIT**

Seaborn just plot things. It won't give you the estimated pdf, just a matplotlib axes. So if you want do do calculations with the kde pdf you'll have to estimate it by yourself.

Seaborn uses statsmodels or scipy under the hood so you can do the same. Statsmodels can give you also the cdf if that is what you are looking for (and maybe scipy but I am not sure). You can compute the levels you are interested in, evaluate the pdf in a grid and pass everything to contourf, which is more or less what seaborn does.

Unfortunately I am not skilled enough yo give you more advice on this (I just use statsmodels for OLS regressions every now and then) but you can look at the code of `kdeplot`and figure out.

Comment: BTW the argument `n_levels` is undocumented AFAICT. Looking at the code it looks like it is passed as `N` to `contour(X, Y, Z, N)` (or `contourf`). <https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/distributions.py#L379-L380>

Comment: yep, and `N` is not the same as `levels` to `contourf`, so I don't think you can use it as such?

Comment: @tom and Goyo, thanks for your help. I think I have clarified my question slightly.

Answer (score -2):

I was just facing the same problem. Something that I don't understand is that why the confidence levels and so the plot changes when the number of bins is changed. You chose bin=40 in the histogram but if you change it you get a different plot.