# Set confidence intervals in seaborn 2D kdeplot #2

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, seaborn, data-analysis

I plot a 2D KDE with seaborn with:

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(scatter_all["s_zscore"], scatter_all["p_zscore"])
```

I want my levels of the density estimation to be meaningful, ie. I wan to mark confidence intervals. Basically I would like to obtain something very close to:
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225307/set-confidence-levels-in-seaborn-kdeplot) but the data are not normalized and it **has to** stay that way.
Could someone please provide me an explanation where, how and why should I change the calculations for the levels? I am looking for a clear statistical explanation as said in my comment below.

Comment: I think the linked answer shows you at least the strategy to pursue here. Don't use seaborn but matplotlib and supply the precalculated confidence intervals as levels to the `contour` function. I guess you should comment on why or in how far this would not work for you.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Yes, the strategy is clear, my problems are: what does the floating point value for "level" mean in? Should I calculate the "levels" based on the histogram as in the provided answer? What does the proportionality of bins to likelihood mean and is it true for non-normalized data?  
I wanted a more clear answer with an explanation from the statistical side.

Comment: Without having spend any deeper thoughts on this (yet), I can tell that you will benefit strongly from making those points clear *inside the question*.